# How to use nested arrays in props in vue3?

Tags: vuejs3, vue-sfc

I'm using SFC and a setup script with Vue3 (and typescript), and I can't seem to create a prop that's a nested array:

```
const props = defineProps({
    title: String,
    desc: String,
    columns: Array<Array<String>>,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#typescript-only-features

The syntax for typescript is different:

```js
const props = defineProps<{
  foo: string
  bar?: number
}>()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you would be looking at something like this.

```
const props = defineProps<{
  title: string;
  desc: string;
  columns: string[][];
}>()
```

If you are using optional props I would also recommend looking at `withDefaults`.